# How to write macro in c in this case?

Tags: c, macros

Given the following function in c:

```
int reset_values_of_string(char* s, int to_new_val){
   int l = strlen(s);
   int was_changed = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<l; i++) {
      if(s[i] != to_new_val) was_changed=1;
      s[i] = to_new_val;
   }
   return was_changed;
}
```

Can I write this function as MACRO (#define) in C? that will do exactly the same and will return this value ?

In addition, what is bascially preferred? to implement it with macro or with function like that i write it above.

Comment: You can do almost everything with macros... if it's a good idea to do so is another story. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried it? What happened? Why do you want to use a macro? Did you check if defining that function as `static inline int reset_values_of_string()...` also does the trick?

Comment: may I ask why do you need a macro in this case? The function above looks like a perfectly valid solution

Comment: A function is always preferred. You'd only use a macro if you have some exotic requirement. Although writing macros which both declare variables and return a value is hard to do in any good way. You'd end up using file scope variables or non-standard extensions etc, since you can't really return a local variable value from a macro.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I write this function as MACRO (#define) in C? That will do exactly the same and will return this value

**Yes**, and it will be **close enough to the function**.

> What is basically preferred?

A **function** would be preferred.

Modern compilers can choose to automatically [inline functions](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/analyzer/developer-docs/IPA.html) if they deem it a better option. You may also encourage compilers to inline functions.